# How to remove top bar that has search, settings, Help etc. options in SharePoint online communication site

Tags: sharepoint-online, communication-site

I don't want users to see the top bar it should only be visible to site owners.
[image]

Comment: Thanks in advance.

Comment: As @Kalpesh Vaghela said, this is by design and there is generally no way to change it. To address your concern about the situation, we’d suggest you go to feedback on this issue, this is the best platform to let us hear from you and make our products and services better for you and others. The more votes, the easier it is to be seen. https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/06735c62-321c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to remove top bar without injecting our custom css.

Below are some articles which can help you to inject your custom **CSS** using SPFx exntesion.

- https://www.sharepointeurope.com/sharepoint-online-how-to-inject-custom-css-in-modern-sites/
- https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-application-injectcss

> Note
>
> It's not recommendation from Microsoft to play with css element because Microsoft may change page elements and styles at any
> time, rendering your custom CSS useless. It is preferrable to use
> well-known HTML element placeholders.